# In IDEA, how to jump to next occurrence of currently selected text?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IDEA, when I have some text selected (e.g., a symbol), is there a way to quickly jump to the next occurrence of my current selection in the current file? I can do Ctrl+F, F3 and Esc but isn't there a quicker way, without the need to go through the find panel?

Edit: to make it clear, I am looking for a way to do this ***without the Find panel being open***.

(One thing I noticed: the area behind scrollbar automatically indicates where else the current selection appears in the current file. Maybe there is some command to go to the next occurrence as indicated by the gutter?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select desired text and press <kbd>CTRL+F3</kbd> to search for current selection, and then <kbd>F3</kbd> for next ocurrence (or keep pressing <kbd>CTRL+F3</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

Try [BrowseWordAtCaret](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/201?pr=idea), it is much better than `CTRL+F3` which others suggested.

Description:

> Allows to easily browse next/previous word at caret and highlight other appearances of selected word.
>
> Usage: Browse with CTRL-ALT-UP, CTRL-ALT-DOWN (note: on default-keymap this shortcut is also for next/previous occurrence).

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your search dialog open, use <kbd>F3</kbd> to move to the next occurrence.  Use <kbd>Shift+F3</kbd> to move back an occurrence.

Comment: As noted in the question, I am aware of the method involving standard Find (Ctrl+F) panel. I am looking for something quicker, if there is any.